# Azure Function Storage Account Not Linking File Service On Create

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-storage-files

When creating an Azure function with an Dedicated (Standard) App Service Plan  the file service I'm expecting to get "linked" up isn't getting "linked" to the storage account. However the Storage account does get created correctly. When I go to the Azure Storage Accounts blade and find the file storage, Azure doesn't have the file service linked to the Storage Account. I don't see any linked File Shares when using the Windows desktop software, Microsoft Azure Storage Explorer (0.9.6).

When I go to the Azure Function's Advanced Tools (Kudo) I can see the storage account folders "Data", "LogFiles", and "Site" with the wwwroot I'm expecting to find. However due to certain network restrictions I can't upload the code through the web-site so that option is out.

When creating a Consumption based plan everything links up nicely and I can manage them in the Azure Storage Explorer app. How can I get my already created File Service File Share linked to my already created Azure Function so I can manage it in the desktop app and get things appearing correctly linked up in the Storage Explorer?

Comment: When running in a dedicated SKU (Basic/Standard), the storage backend is a bit different, you can't see it in Storage Explorer. There are many other ways you can deploy to it, [Zip deploy being just one of them](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/deployment-zip-push). Or the new [Run-from-zip aka zipfs](https://github.com/Azure/app-service-announcements/issues/84) - beware this one is still _preview_ stuff

Comment: I'm still able to deploy via Visual Studio Publish from my code. However that's not ideal because it's a local copy that hasn't been "validated" like the deployed code has (because human error not recognizing local changes occurs). Ideally a VSTS publish would be established. Using Zip file deploy with precompiled C# code I assume you would have to take the bin/release/[net_version]/* and publish that (taking out the local settings file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a solution for you to refer, as it works on my side.
In portal, Application Settings Tab, add two application settings below:

- `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` storage account connectionstring
- `WEBSITE_CONTENTSHARE` file share name

And some explanations for you.

When creating a function app, the storage account we specified is mainly used to store logs and files like host locks.
Only for function app created in consumption plan, it automatically adds the two application settings above and uses File Share to store whole function app by default.

As [Azure document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-app-settings#websitecontentazurefileconnectionstring) says, the File Share related settings is for consumption plan only. It seems not an expected operation for function created in app service plan, but it works in practice anyway.

---

**Update**

For a function app created in app service plan, assume its files are stored in place A(somewhere on the server). It works well and kudu displays files stored in A. So far it has nothing to do with file share.

Then we add the two settings, and assume the file share is B. 
System retains old files(if exist) in B and creates an empty function app in it. From now on, system targets at and leverage files in B, as long as the "link"(two settings) exist. In portal, kudu or app service editor, we see files in B and also changes will be saved there.

And if we delete the "link", everything returns to A. Need to wait a little while for system "redirecting".

All explanation is based on my test(dozens of times) since it's an unexpected operation and has no document description.

Comment: How do I discover what the File Service name is if it's not linked? Is it the portion of the connection string that identifies the Account Name? I ask because when linked using that account name I don't see the wwwroot folder like I do otherwise (but it shows in advanced tools).

Comment: The "link" is not an expected operation in app service plan(opposite to consumption plan), we build the link manually. So the file share name depends on our choice(existing file share or new name both ok). After the settings added, function app will be "linked" to the file share we specified. Need to refresh in file share or kudu to see the change immediately.

Comment: @JustinNeff Any update on this issue or further questions?

Comment: When I "published" manually from Visual Studio 2017 the Azure Functions Appeared in the project but I couldn't find them in Kudo. So what you're saying is I have to "manually create" the file share by "Linking" to one. When I used random characters it made a new one, but the published Function was still functional, is that expected functionality?

Comment: If publish using VS, you are supposed to see precompiled code under `site\wwwroot\bin` folder as dll file. And it seems unexpected about `still functional`. Published function became invalid and disappeared from Functions list in portal after several refreshing on my side.  
Besides, if you have found any other way useful, you can give up this one as it's an unexpected operation and digging into this seems a waste of your time. But if you are curious about this, see my updated answer and feel free to ask any further questions.

Comment: I don't understand why Microsoft has different flavor for the same offering. Only .NET delivers log to Blob, while it's File Share for Java & other.
Even if with Java Function App, there's different log delivery behavior for Consumption Plan vs App Service Plan.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/troubleshoot-diagnostic-logs